# How do I handle dismissing a dialog that could appear at anytime during my automated test?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm trying to make an automated unit test with Android Espresso.

I have a dialog that is triggered by push notification events which could appear at any time while the test runs. I want the unit test to be able to dismiss the dialog in the event that it appears without breaking the unit test, is this possible?

I have code that checks once after launch for the dialog and dismisses it if it's present or continues the unit test if not present.  I want to be able to make this check anytime the dialog shows up, which could be at any time, instead of just once after launch.

I'm trying to find a way to do this without adding the check after every line of code in the unit test.

I tried using `handler.postDelayed` to just check frequently but it didn't seem to work like I would expect when running from a unit test.

Comment: Why is a test build paying attention to push notifications? Shouldn't it be paying attention to messages from some sort of test mock, so you control if/when such messages arrive?

Comment: I would like to test real push notifications and not mock situation if possible, that's part of the question.  I'm looking for an answer that helps me solve the problem or one that explains why it should be avoided or can't be done correctly.  If you think test cases should be limited to not run with real data and only mocked data and can provide supporting material on why that is so I would accept that as a solution.  The dialog shows up randomly based on other api results as well even if push notifications are disabled, I could mock everything but would like to test real world data too.

Comment: "I would like to test real push notifications and not mock situation if possible" -- but, isn't that basically testing Google? If you have done a good job of isolating your push message processing, the difference between the mocks and real push messages is nearly all Google tech (their servers, Play Services, etc.). On a manual basis, testing this is fine. I just don't know how you're going to get reliable automated tests, particularly for use in CI servers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a Dialog that implements the DialogInterface you should be about to add a onShowListener to the dialog before showing

Comment: And simply close the dialog onShow().
provided you parsed the dialog in the onShow(dialog).
which should look like this @Override onShow(dialog){ dialog.dismiss }

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment made by @CommonsWare. However, in your case, you might consider having a flag which says if the application is in testing mode or not. Hence you might consider having a variable like the following.

```
public static boolean TESTING = true;
```

When you are creating a production build, turn off the testing mode simply by setting the variable as `false`.

Hence, before showing an `AlertDialog`, you might consider checking the variable and decide whether you will pop up a dialog or not.